# Error when parsing YAML file on GOLANG when there's a dash before the square brackets list

Tags: go, yaml

When parsing a YAML file in GOLANG with gopkg.in/yaml.v3, if the YAML file has a dash before the brackets then it doesn't read it.

I have a YAML file with a syntax similar to this:

```
servers:

    - server_name: ratamahatta
      server_groups:
          - [r1, r2, r3]

    - server_name: kaiowas
      server_groups:
          - [c1, c2]
```

If I use the following struct in GO:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type S struct {
    Servers []struct {
        ServerName string   `yaml:"server_name"`
        ServerGroups []string `yaml:"server_groups"`
    } `yaml:"servers"`
}

func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("example2.yaml")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var s S

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    
    fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", s.Servers[0].ServerGroups[0])
}
```

I get:

```
  line 5: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
  line 9: cannot unmarshal !!seq into string
```

But, if I remove the "-" before the brackets:

```
servers:

    - server_name: ratamahatta
      server_groups:
           [r1, r2, r3]

    - server_name: kaiowas
      server_groups:
           [c1, c2]
```

Then it works perfectly.

If I change this:

```
ServerGroups []string `yaml:"server_groups"`
```

To

```
ServerGroups struct {} `yaml:"server_groups"`
```

Then I get

```
cannot unmarshal !!seq into struct {}
```

So basically I can't figure out how to read the YAML sequence in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The YAML you are processing `- [r1, r2, r3]` is a [Sequence of Sequences](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#example-sequence-of-sequences) meaning there could be additional entries e.g.

```
- server_name: ratamahatta
      server_groups:
          - [r1, r2, r3]
          - [r4, r5, r6]
```

So to parse this you need an extra dimension i.e. `[][]string`. A working sample follows ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0JWt_ZhAyHm)):

```
const testYaml = `servers:
    - server_name: ratamahatta
      server_groups:
          - [r1, r2, r3]
          - [r4, r5, r6]
    - server_name: kaiowas
      server_groups:
          - [c1, c2]
`

type S struct {
    Servers []struct {
        ServerName   string     `yaml:"server_name"`
        ServerGroups [][]string `yaml:"server_groups"`
    } `yaml:"servers"`
}

func main() {
    var s S
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(testYaml), &s); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", s.Servers[0].ServerGroups[0]) // []string{"r1", "r2", "r3"}
    fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", s.Servers[0].ServerGroups[1]) // []string{"r4", "r5", "r6"}
    fmt.Printf("Value: %#v\n", s.Servers[1].ServerGroups[0]) // []string{"c1", "c2"}
}
```